# Spring Boot OAuth 2.0 UserDetails user not found

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, userdetailsservice

I am new to Spring Boot, and I am trying to configure OAuth 2.0. The problem I am having at this moment is that I keep getting the following message when I attempt to request for an access token:

> {
>       "error": "invalid_grant",
>       "error_description": "Bad credentials"
>   }

The error message in the Spring Boot console says that the user cannot be found.

: Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
: User 'stromero' not found
: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'authenticationAuditListener'

I have implemented a custom user that has already been saved to a database using JPA, I am unable to figure why Spring Security cannot find this user, it may an issue with my logic or configuration. If someone with more experience can look at my code and perhaps guide me to the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

This is the HTTP Request:

> POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost:8181
>   Authorization: Basic YnJvd3NlcjpzZWNyZXQ=
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   username=stromero&password=password&client_id=browser&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password

These are the classes that I used to implement my custom user and OAuth 2.0

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<CustomUser, String> {

public CustomUser findByUsername(String name);
}
```

Below is the custom user I have created

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "custom_user")
 public class CustomUser {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column(name = "username", unique=true, nullable = false)
private String username;
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;
@ElementCollection
private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

public List<String> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Below is a customdetails service that reads the user information from the database and returns it as a UserDetails Object

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    CustomUser customUser = userRepository.findByUsername(s);

    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    return new User(
            customUser .getUsername(),
            customUser .getPassword().toLowerCase(),
            enabled,
            accountNonExpired,
            credentialsNonExpired,
            accountNonLocked,
            getAuthorities(customUser.getRoles()));
}
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(roles);
    return authList;
}


public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (String role : roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
    return authorities;
}
}
```

The class below is a data structure that holds both the UserDetailsService and ClientDetailsService

```
public class ClientAndUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService,
    ClientDetailsService {

    private final ClientDetailsService clients;

    private final UserDetailsService users;

    private final ClientDetailsUserDetailsService clientDetailsWrapper;

    public ClientAndUserDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clients,
                                       UserDetailsService users) {
        super();
        this.clients = clients;
        this.users = users;
        clientDetailsWrapper = new ClientDetailsUserDetailsService(this.clients);
    }

    @Override
    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId)
            throws ClientRegistrationException {
        return clients.loadClientByClientId(clientId);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserDetails user = null;
        try{
            user = users.loadUserByUsername(username);
        }catch(UsernameNotFoundException e){
            user = clientDetailsWrapper.loadUserByUsername(username);
        }
        return user;
    }
    }
```

The class below is my configuration for OAuth 2.0 using Spring Boot

```
 @Configuration
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration {

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
protected static class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    protected void registerAuthentication(
            final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServer extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").anonymous();

        // Require all GET requests to have client "read" scope
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")
                .access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");

        // Require all POST requests to have client "write" scope
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/**")
                .access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 100)
protected static class AuthorizationServer extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private ClientAndUserDetailsService combinedService;

    public AuthorizationServer() throws Exception {

        ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService = new InMemoryClientDetailsServiceBuilder()
                .withClient("browser")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read","write")
                .resourceIds("message")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(7200)
                .and()
                .build();

        // Create a series of hard-coded users.
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = new CustomUserDetailsService();
        combinedService = new ClientAndUserDetailsService(clientDetailsService,   userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() throws Exception {
        return combinedService;
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return combinedService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService());
    }

}

}
```

Below is my pom.xml file

```
    <properties>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.8</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Postgres JDBC Driver -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1002-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate validator -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: I can't see anything (are you sure the user is in the database, and that you are connecting to that database)? There are odd things in your code though (none of which is necessarily going to cause your symptoms): 1. the repository implies the primary key is a `String` but the `@Entity` has `Long`; 2. I don't understand the joint user/client details service; 3. you appear to try and make the /token endpoint available to anonymous users; 4. you are using client credentials in form parameters but you haven't told the auth server you want to do that. Maybe you could share a complete project?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tested the repository and it is able to retrieve the user, with that being said I will use the long as the primary key. I will work on getting rid of the combined service. I am not sure how to handle 3 and 4. I can't share the entire project, but I have based lot of my source code of the following example, please let me know if this helps.  https://github.com/juleswhite/mobilecloud-14/tree/master/examples/9-VideoServiceWithOauth2 As I stated before the JPA part seems to work with no issue. The OAuth 2.0 flow I am trying to implement is password grant.

Comment: This may also provide more context - > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmCvyg20xi4

Comment: Essentially I want the same thing this person wanted, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179573/spring-security-oauth2-simple-configuration, this is very difficult do you have any detailed documentation that could help explain how to achieve this in Spring Boot

Comment: I don't know why it's so difficult. My answer to that post is still valid, and there are copious sample apps in [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth).

Comment: I think its because I am not as smart as you are :), I will look into your examples and see if I can figure something out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeah, I had the same issue... wanted to use JPA's `UserDetailsService` but the same problem - user couldn't be found... got resolved it eventually, thanks to Dave Syer's OAuth2 samples on GitHub.

The problem seem to be in authenticationManager instance autowired in `@EnableAuthorizationServer AuthorizationServer` class. AuthenticationManager is autowired there and seems to initialize with default `DAOAuthenticationProvider`, and for some reason it doesn't use custom JPA `UserDetailsService` we initialize authenticationManager with in `WebSecurityConfiguration`.

In Dave Syer samples authenticationManager is exposed as a bean in `WebSecurityConfiguration`:

```
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

then in `AuthorizationServer` we autowire authenticationManager as follows:

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Once I did it I finally managed to get my user authenticated against my customer JPA user repository.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I implemented the AuthenticationManager in the same way and was able to get the custom JPA user repository working with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and spent hours investigating the case. As a workaround, if you are using Spring Boot version 1.1.8.RELEASE, downgrade it to 1.0.2.RELEASE. Things went fine that way but I did not investigate yet the reasons of compatibility issue with Spring Boot version 1.1.8.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

InitializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer has default order as

```
static final int DEFAULT_ORDER = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 5000;
```

So it Initializee DaoAuthenticationProvider before custom one.

```
@Order(-5001)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { ... }
```