# Spring Boot OAuth2 with basic authentication and custom UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to configure an OAuth2 server that will be capable to complete the basic OAuth2 flows (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39820_01/doc.11121/gateway_docs/content/oauth_flows.html) for examples).

Apologies for the long question

My first attempt is to be able to perform an **authorization_code** flow.

I have the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig
        extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ....

        @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
              .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
              .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

...

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

My Server configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorServerConfig
        extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
            .checkTokenAccess("authenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        .inMemory()
                .withClient("foo")
                .secret("foo")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code","password", "refresh_token")
                .scopes(new String[] { "read", "write" })
    }
```

And indeed my authorization code flow works ok! Problem start when I try to do a password flow as follows:

```
POST localhost:8200/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept:application/json
Authorization:Basic Zm9vOmZvbw=="
username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=foo&client_id=foo&
```

My problem is that the Authorization header is ignored, whether it is there or not the result is the same, it gives me back the access_token and refresh_token

If I try to enable the basic authentication as follows, enable ClientUserDetailsService, reading clients from database JDBC:

```
public class SecurityConfig
        extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ....

@Bean
public ClientDetailsUserDetailsService   clientDetailsUserDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService){
    // JDBC clientDetailsService
    return new ClientDetailsUserDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
}


        @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
              .userDetailsService(clientDetailsUserDetailsService());
    }

...

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider p = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    p.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    p.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return new ProviderManager(Lists.newArrayList(p));
    //        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    }
```

Now what I have achieved is to have the basic authentication working properly BUT i loose the authorization_code flow since the basic authentication now it is done against the clientid and secret and NOT the user's actual credentials

Am I missing something? How can I have both flows? Please help, I'm struggling for some days now.

Some Similar questions, but without any luck:

- [problems injecting custom userDetailsService in Spring Security OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683166/problems-injecting-custom-userdetailsservice-in-spring-security-oauth2)
- [Spring Boot OAuth 2.0 UserDetails user not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208087/spring-boot-oauth-2-0-userdetails-user-not-found)

Comment: How does this even compile. clientDetailsUserDetailsService accepts one argument..when you call the bean, there's no argument. confused.com

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you've turned on form authentication for clients, you it's using that instead of the Basic header.

```
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security
        .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
        .checkTokenAccess("authenticated()");
}
```

Take out `.allowFormAuthenticationForClients()`.