# How to get who is trying to login using OAuth "authorize" method?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Already solved [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595985/how-to-secure-a-mvc-application-with-oauth2-using-spring). Now after created a custom login page using JSP I'm trying to show to the user what application is trying to get the credentials.

In my web application (the client) I  put this configuration in `application.yml`:

```
server:
    port: 8083
    context-path: /
    session:
      cookie:
        name: UI2SESSION
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: cerberus
      clientSecret: cerberus
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8180/guardiao/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8180/guardiao/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8180/guardiao/user/me
```

When the user try to go to any page in this application he will be redirected to the Guardiao (Guardian) login page (my OAuth2 server).

The method the client is using to authenticate the user against the OAuth server is `oauth/authorize`

All is working fine but would be nice if I could get some client information to show to the user at login time in my custom page so the user can confirm the application he is using.

At OAuth server side (in the Guardiao) I have

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   // some blah blah blah

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       http.csrf().disable()
           .requestMatchers()
           .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
       .and()
           .authorizeRequests()
           .anyRequest()
           .authenticated()
       .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/loginPage")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/loginPage?error=true")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
        .permitAll();
   }


}
```

and the loginPage.jsp have a simple form with username and password fields to post to `/login` endpoint as usual.

What I need to know is: is there some JSTL tags to get what client (the application the user is trying to use and is asking the login to the Guardiao) to show in my login page like `Application XXXXXX is asking for your credentials` ? In this case, the `Cerberus` application.

The client is comming from database (table `oauth_client_details`) and all the project you can find [here](https://github.com/icemagno/geoinfra/tree/master/cerberus/guardiao)

Answer (score 0):

After years of research and a lot of money I found the solution:
Just intercept the `loginForm` controller and get the `SavedRequest` attribute from Session. You can get the `client_id` attribute and read it from database or just pass it thru.

You'll find `client.getAdditionalInformation()` very useful too if you use database to store your clients.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void setClientDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Model model, HttpSession session, @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error) {

        try {
            SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest)session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");
            /*  Values are: client_id, redirect_uri, response_type and state  */
            String client_id = savedRequest.getParameterValues("client_id")[0]; 
            ClientDetails client = clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId( client_id );
            model.addAttribute( "clientId", client.getClientId() );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            model.addAttribute( "directAccess", true ); // <<-- Tell the JSP page to hide the login form and warn the user to not access this page directly
        }

        return "loginPage";
    }   


}
```